# Bit wise Operation Logic

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two equal sized arrays ( array1 and array2 ) of 0's and 1's. How do I get all the arrays whose bit wise union with array1 result into array2 ? For example,if array1 = [1, 1, 1] and array2 = [1, 1, 1]. Output should be all eight arrays : [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], ...., [1, 1, 1] . Are there efficient solutions to it or only brute force is the way ?

My try :
I tried to calculate bit wise difference first and if any of bit is negative then return false( not possible to combine first array with any kind of array to get array2). If all bits are non-negative then .... if bit in difference is 0 then it can be replaced by 0 or 1 either( this is wrong assumption albeit and fails for if array1= [0,0] , array2= [0,0], and if any bit in difference is 0 then required array has to have 1 at that place to make it 1

Comment: Well! Show us how you tried to solve it and where you are stuck at ?

Comment: I tried to calculate bit wise difference first and if any of bit is negative then return false( not possible to combine first array with any kind of array to get array2). If all bits are non-negative then ....
if bit in difference is 0 then it can be replaced by 0 or 1 either( this is wrong assumption albeit and fails for if array1= [0,0] , array2= [0,0], 
and if any bit in difference is 0 then required array has to have 1 at that place to make it 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct the digit options for each slot `i` by evaluating:

```
for d in (0, 1):
    if (array1[i] or d) == array2[i]):
        digits[i].append(d)
```

Then you just need to iterate over `i`.
The objective is to construct a list of lists: `[[0,1],[1],[0,1]]` showing the valid digits in each slot. Then you can use `itertools.product()` to construct all of the valid arrays:

```
arrays = list(itertools.product(*digits))
```

You can put all this together using list comprehensions and this would result in:

```
list(it.product(*[[d for d in (0, 1) if (x or d) == y] for x, y in zip(array1, array2)]))
```

In action:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> a1, a2 = [1,1,1], [1,1,1]
>>> list(it.product(*[[d for d in (0, 1) if (x or d) == y] for x, y in zip(a1, a2)]))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]

>>> a1, a2 = [1,0,0], [1,1,1]
>>> list(it.product(*[[d for d in (0, 1) if (x or d) == y] for x, y in zip(a1, a2)]))
[(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]

>>> a1, a2 = [1,0,0], [0,1,1]
>>> list(it.product(*[[d for d in (0, 1) if (x or d) == y] for x, y in zip(a1, a2)]))
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would go about solving this problem:

1. First, let's think about this. You need to find *all* arrays of binary values that, when combined (via some operator) with a known binary value, = a new binary value. Don't try to solve the problem yet. Assume you need to go from 00 to 11. How many possible answers are there? Assume you need to go from 11 to 11. How many possible answers are there? Can you do any better (in the worst case) than a brute force approach? That'll give you a complexity bound.
2. With that rough bound in mind, tackle the bits of the question that are a bit curious. Drill down onto the question a little bit more. What is the 'bitwise union operator'? Is it 'and'? Is it 'or'? Is it something more complicated? 'Bitwise Union' sounds like `B[i] = A[i] OR X[i]`, but anyone asking that question *could* mean something else..
3. Depending on the answer to questions 1 and 2, you have a lot to work with here. I can think of a few different options, but I think from here you can come up with an algorithm.
4. Once you have a solution, you need to think about "Can I do a better job here'? A lot of that goes back to the initial impressions about the problem and how they're constructed, and what/how much you think you can optimize.

Comment: array1 = [True, True, False, False]
array2 = [True, False, True, False]
Bit wise union is 'OR' here. Seems like it's not efficiently solvable ?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I will explain the following with an example input:
`A = [0 0 1 0 1 1], B = [1 1 1 0 1 1]`*

Assuming you want to calculate `X` for the equations `A OR X = B`, let us see what are the options for each choice of bit in A and B:

```
A    OR    X   =   B
--------------------
0          0       0
0          1       1
1          N.A.    0
1         (0,1)    1
```

1. If any bit in `A` is 1, and its corresponding `B` bit is 0, there are no solutions possible. Return an empty set.
2. If the corresponding bits in `A` and `B` are 1, the corresponding bit in `X` does not matter.

Now, see that one solution for `X` is `B` itself, (if condition #1, as stated above, is satisfied). Hence, lets construct a number `start_num = B`. This will be one solution, and the other solutions will be constructed from this.

*`start_num = B = [1 1 1 0 1 1]`*

The 'choice' bits are those where `X` can take any value, i.e. those positions where `A=1` and `B=1`. Let us make another number `choice = A AND B`, so that `choice = 1` denotes those positions. Also notice that, if there are `k` positions where `choice = 1`, the total number of solutions is `2^k`.

*`choice = A AND B = [0 0 1 0 1 1]`* ,hence, *`k = 3`*

Store these 'choice' positions in an array (of length `k`), starting from the right (LSB = 0). Let us call this array `pos_array`.

*`pos_array = [0 1 3]`*

Notice that all the 'choice' bits in `start_num` are set to 1. Hence, all the other solutions will have some (`1 <= p <= k`) of these bits set to 0. Now that we know which bits are to be changed, we need to make these solutions in an efficient manner.

This can be done by making all solutions in an order where the difference between the previous solution and the current one is just at one position, hence making it efficient to calculate the solutions. For example, if we have two 'choice' bits, the following explains the difference between simply running through all combinations in an arithmetic progression, and going through them in a 1-bit-change order:

```
1-bit-toggle-order                decreasing order
----------------------            ----------------------
1 1   // start                    1 1   // start                       
1 0   // toggle bit 0             1 0   // subtract 1
0 0   // toggle bit 1             0 1   // subtract 1
0 1   // toggle bit 0             0 0   // subtract 1
```

(We want to exploit the speed of bitwise operations, hence we will use the 1-bit-toggle order).

Now, we will build each solution: (This is not actual C code, just an explanation)

```
addToSet(start_num);    // add the initial solution to the set

for(i=1; i<2^k; i++)
{
    pos = 0;
    count = i;
    while( ( count & 1) != 0)
    {
        count = count>>1;
        pos++;
    }

    toggle(start_num[pos_array[pos]]);    // update start_num by toggling the desired bit
    addToSet(start_num);    // Add the updated vector to the set
}
```

If this code is run on the above example, the following toggle statements will be executed:

```
toggle(start_num[0])
toggle(start_num[1])
toggle(start_num[0])
toggle(start_num[3])
toggle(start_num[0])
toggle(start_num[1])
toggle(start_num[0])
```

, which will result in the following additions:

```
addToSet([1 1 1 0 1 0])
addToSet([1 1 1 0 0 0])
addToSet([1 1 1 0 0 1])
addToSet([1 1 0 0 0 1])
addToSet([1 1 0 0 0 0])
addToSet([1 1 0 0 1 0])
addToSet([1 1 0 0 1 1])
```

, which, in addition to the already-present initial solution `[1 1 1 0 1 1]`, completes the set.

---

NOTE: I am not an expert in bitwise operations, besides other things. I think there are better ways to write the algorithm, making better use of bit-access pointers and bitwise binary operations (and will be glad if someone can suggest improvements). What I am proposing with this solution is the general approach to this problem.